# How to edit a Makefile inside a Netbeans Project?

Tags: netbeans, makefile, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to edit the file `Makefile-variables.mk` inside my C++ project directory, but Netbeans keeps regenerating the file to it's old settings. Now, the header clearly says 'do not edit' so I am guessing this is not the way to do it. How would I edit my Makefile so I can change the destination directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured all of these options can be edited inside the GUI by right clicking on the project and going to Properties.